# Embedded a #[pyclass] in another #[pyclass]

Tags: python, rust, pyo3, python-bindings

I am trying to implement a cache for the private variable of any python class.

Let's suppose I have this:

```
#[pyclass]
struct ClassA {
    pv: Py<PyAny>, // GIL independent type, storable in another #[pyclass]
    field_a: Py<PyAny>,
}

#[pyclass]
struct ClassB {
    class_a: Py<ClassA>,
    field_b: Py<PyAny>,
}
```

In the impls of `ClassA`, I have a method attempting to 'put' a reference of the `ClassA` object into the `ClassB`'s `class_a` field. And return a newly instantiated `ClassB` object.

```
#[pymethods]
impl ClassA {
    fn ret_class_b {&self, field_b: &PyAny) -> PyResult<ClassB> {
        let class_a: Py<ClassA> = Py::clone_ref(self, field_b.py());
        ClassB {
            class_a: class_a,
            field_b: field_b.into_py(),
        }
    }
}
```

The above does not compile.

The issue is how do I get `&Py<ClassA>` from the receiver of the method so as to return another object where the receiver is referred to as a field in that object?

## Edit / Update

Thanks to [@cafce25](https://stackoverflow.com/users/442760/cafce25) for his reminder on giving fully reproducible codes and the error from the compiler.

Here is it:

```html
use pyo3::{
    prelude::{*, Py, PyAny},
};

#[pymodule]
fn stackoverflowqn(py: Python, pymod: &PyModule) -> PyResult<()> {
    #[pyclass(name = "class_a")]
    #[derive(Clone, Debug)]
    pub struct ClassA {
        pv: Option<Py<PyAny>>, // private value
        field_a: Py<PyAny>,
    }

    #[pyclass]
    #[derive(Clone, Debug)]

    pub struct ClassB {
        class_a: Py<ClassA>,
        field_b: Py<PyAny>,
    }

    #[pymethods]
    impl ClassA {
        #[new]
        pub fn __new__(_slf: PyRef<'_, Self>, field_a: PyObject) -> PyResult<ClassA> {
            Ok(ClassA {
                pv: None,
                field_a: field_a,
            })
        }

        fn ret_class_b {&self, field_b: &PyAny) -> PyResult<ClassB> {
            let class_a: Py<ClassA> = Py::clone_ref(self, field_b.py());
            Ok(ClassB {
                class_a: class_a,
                field_b: field_b.into_py(),
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the compiler error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `ClassA: pyo3::IntoPy<pyo3::Py<ClassA>>` is not satisfied
  --> crates\cached-property\src\stackoverflow.rs:36:53
   |
36 |                 pyo3::IntoPy::<Py<ClassA>>::into_py(pty_getter, py);
   |                 ----------------------------------- ^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `pyo3::IntoPy<pyo3::Py<ClassA>>` is not implemented for `ClassA`
   |                 |
   |                 required by a bound introduced by this call
   |
   = help: the trait `pyo3::IntoPy<pyo3::Py<PyAny>>` is implemented for `ClassA`
```

Comment: "The above does not compile." Why? Please [edit] your question to add the full error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The issue is how do I get `&Py<ClassA>` from the receiver of the method so as to return another object where the receiver is referred to as a field in that object?

If I understood correctly your problem is constructing `Py<ClassA>` from `&ClassA` available in your method through `&self`. I think what you are looking for is a change in your method signature. There is little documentation on this in the user guide, but if you look at the examples in [`PyRef`](https://docs.rs/pyo3/latest/pyo3/pycell/struct.PyRef.html#examples) you see that you can pass an instance of `PyRef<'_, Self>` into your method instead of `&self`:

> You can use `PyRef` as an alternative to a `&self` receiver

You can convert `PyRef` into a `Py` pointer simply by calling [`.into()`](https://docs.rs/pyo3/latest/pyo3/struct.Py.html#impl-From%3CPyRef%3C%27a%2C%20T%3E%3E-for-Py%3CT%3E).

I've made some changes to your example and this compiles on my computer:

```rust
#[pyclass]
struct ClassA {
    pv: Py<PyAny>, // GIL independent type, storable in another #[pyclass]
    field_a: Py<PyAny>,
}

#[pymethods]
impl ClassA {
    fn ret_class_b(slf: PyRef<'_, Self>, field_b: Py<PyAny>) -> PyResult<ClassB> {
        Ok(ClassB {
            class_a: slf.into(),
            field_b,
        })
    }
}

#[pyclass]
struct ClassB {
    class_a: Py<ClassA>,
    field_b: Py<PyAny>,
}
```